# Problems in Anylogic with queue and Timemeasure

Tags: time, queue, anylogic

I have two questions.
The first is: How can I set an exit time from a queue block? I’m supposed to simulate a queue of waiting vehicles, but these have to go out at a regular time. I tried both using the option enable exit on timeout but it does not work, both using the service block by setting a proper delay time, but is this solution correct?
The second question is: How do I measure the time an agent travels through the system? I thought about using timeMeasurestart and end blocks but how do I get time value? Sorry for my ignorance in Analogic, but anyone doesn't give me a guide.

I posted an image of my model

[image: I posted an image of my model]

Thanks for all your answers!

Comment: Hi @Marco, welcome to SOF, great to have you. In the future, please ask questions individually, this is not a forum but a Q&A place :) See https://www.benjamin-schumann.com/blog/2021/4/1/how-to-win-at-anylogic-on-stackoverflow for more details

Comment: Hi Benjamin thanks for your answer. I apologize for asking two questions.

Comment: No problem @Marco. if it was helpful, please upvote the answer, helps others in the future, see https://stackoverflow.com/help/why-vote

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How can I set an exit time from a queue block? I’m supposed to simulate a queue of waiting vehicles, but these have to go out at a regular time.

This is not how queues work, they are passive elements. However, you can use a "Wait" block and create an event that calls `wait.free(myAgent)` whenever you need that agent.

> How do I measure the time an agent travels through the system? I thought about using timeMeasurestart and end blocks but how do I get time value?

Correct approach. You retrieve individual durations for agents by accessing the `dataset` within this block, see the [help](https://anylogic.help/library-reference-guides/process-modeling-library/timemeasureend.html#timemeasureend).

Alternatively, you can add variables to your agent type flowing through the system and measure the time entering/exiting manually in the flow blocks (`agent.myTimeStart=time()`).

There are many ways. Since you are new, the best course for you is to explore all the step-by-step tutorials in the help (as they cover these basics) and explore ALL example models to learn how to do things like these :)